# BeanIO - How to map abstract class or interface as record or segment

Tags: java, annotations, marshalling, bean-io

How to use BeanIO annotations to define a segment of an interface?
In my example, I can only obtain the lineResponse with only @Field information, @Segment is not visible.

ParserWriter result:

`2021051211362850OK       Tutto bene`

**Desidered result of 1 line:**

`2021051211362850EPPDNY81            D91138414510         20210512        F          OK       Tutto bene`

Response.class that contains list of LineResponse.class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Group(minOccurs=0, maxOccurs= -1, type = Response.class)
public class Response {
    @Record(minOccurs=1, collection = List.class, name="responseLineList", type=LineResponse.class)
    List<LineResponse> responseLines;
}
```

In the following class LineResponse.class, it is present a @Segment with an interface.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Record
public class LineResponse implements Serializable {
    
    @Field(ordinal = 1, required = true, length=16, format = "yyyyMMddhhmmssSS")
    Date elaboratedOn;

    @Segment(ordinal =2, name="requestLine", minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
    RequestLine line;

    @Field(ordinal = 3, required = true, length=9)
    String errorCode;
    @Field(ordinal = 4, length=36)
    String errorMessage;
}
```

Code of interface:

```
public interface RequestLine {}
```

Code of concrete TestLine class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Record
public class TestLine implements RequestLine {

    @Field(required = true, length=4, maxLength=4)
    private String recordType; 
    @Field(required = true, length=1, maxLength=1)
    private String messageKO;
    @Field(required = true, length=1, maxLength=1)
    private String messageOK;
    @Field(required = true, length=1, maxLength=1)
    private String divisionCode;
    @Field(required = true, length=13, maxLength=13)
    private Integer progressive; 
    @Field(required = true, length=1, maxLength=1, defaultValue = "D")
    private String prefixItemCode;
    @Field(required = true, length=9, maxLength=9)
    private String itemCode; 
}
```

Code of concrete TestLineB class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Record
public class TestLineB implements RequestLine {

    @Field(required = true, length=9, maxLength=9)
    private String itemCode;
    @Field(required = true, length=7, maxLength=7)
    private BigDecimal quantity;
    @Field(required = false, length=1, maxLength=1)
    private String cancellation;
    @Field(required = true, length=3, maxLength=3)
    private String productionLine;
}
```

This is the code of my test with StreamFactory

```
// Filling mock Response with lines
LineResponse lineResponse = new LineResponse();
        lineResponse .setElaboratedOn(new Date());
        lineResponse .setLine(testLine);
        lineResponse .setErrorCode("OK");
        lineResponse .setErrorMessage("Tutto bene");

List<LineResponse> lineResponseList = new ArrayList<>();
        lineResponseList .add(lineResponse );
        
Response response = new Response();
response.setResponseLine(lineResponseList);

Writer writer = new StringWriter();

String writerName = "ResponseFile";
 // create a StreamFactory
            StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
            factory.define(
                    new StreamBuilder(writerName)
                            .writeOnly()
                            .format("fixedlength")
                            .parser(new FixedLengthParserBuilder())
                            .addGroup(Response.class)
            );

BeanWriter out = factory.createWriter(writerName, writer);
// JAVA to Writer
out.write(response);
```

Comment: I've never tried to use interfaces for `BeanIO`, I've always mapped the actual classes in the `mapping.xml` file and don't know the annotations that well. Why do you use an "empty" / marker interface? How many implementations are there for the `RequestLine` interface?

Comment: I've, at the moment, 4 RequestLine. The response have always the same structure. I wanted to avoid implementing a response for every request.